# Disconnect signal that connected from script

Tags: events, godot

I connected signal when a scene is instantiated.

```
# AsteroidSpawner.gd
func spawn_asteroid():
    var asteroid_instance = asteroid_scene.instance()
    asteroid_instance.connect("destroy", self, "handle_asteroid_destroy")
    add_child(asteroid_instance)
func handle_asteroid_destroy():
    ... # TO SOME STUFFS WHEN ASTEROID DESTROYED...
    ... # How to disconnect this handler from here?
```

But the problem is, I want to disconnect handle_asteroid_destroy handler when object destroyed(or will destroy, use queue_free). How do I disconnect signal on specific object? Is Godot Engine will free the handler automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to worry about disconnecting a signal when an object is destroyed -- the engine will handle that for you. See the [connect docs](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-connect):

> If the target is destroyed in the game’s lifecycle, the connection will be lost.

You can also use [`CONNECT_ONESHOT`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#enum-object-connectflags) to ensure that a signal is disconnected after firing once, though it is not necessary in this situation.